# Pandas Merge dataframes: merge data into df1 from two sources df2 and df3

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

Code:
d1 = {'EUtranCellFDDId': ['HMSHTX04BBULTE029491511', 'HMSHTX04BBULTE029491531','HMSHTX04BBULTE029491521','CYPRTXKEBBULTE030237129', 'CYPRTXKEBBULTE030237127','CYPRTXKEBBULTE030237128'], 'noOfTxAntennas': [33000,33000,33000,22000,22000,22000]}

df11 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)

d2 = {'EUtranCellFDDId': ['CYPRTXKEBBULTE030237129', 'CYPRTXKEBBULTE030237127','CYPRTXKEBBULTE030237128'], 'earfcndl': [41374, 40978,41176]}

df22 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)

d3 = {'EUtranCellFDDId': ['HMSHTX04BBULTE029491511', 'HMSHTX04BBULTE029491531','HMSHTX04BBULTE029491521'], 'earfcndl': [8665, 8665,8665]}

df33 = pd.DataFrame(data=d3)

df=pd.merge(df11,df22,left_on='EUtranCellFDDId',right_on='EUtranCellFDDId',how='left')

df=pd.merge(df,df33,left_on='EUtranCellFDDId',right_on='EUtranCellFDDId',how='left')

Output

```
EUtranCellFDDId noOfTxAntennas  earfcndl_x  earfcndl_y
```

0   HMSHTX04BBULTE029491511 33000   NaN 8665.0
1   HMSHTX04BBULTE029491531 33000   NaN 8665.0
2   HMSHTX04BBULTE029491521 33000   NaN 8665.0
3   CYPRTXKEBBULTE030237129 22000   41374.0 NaN
4   CYPRTXKEBBULTE030237127 22000   40978.0 NaN
5   CYPRTXKEBBULTE030237128 22000   41176.0 NaN[Current output snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3B8v.jpg)

Comment: can you please include 1) sample data? 2) the code you tried and 3) desired output. Starting with #1, you can simply copy and paste your dataframes into you stackoverflow question  using the Code Sample *{ }* feature.

Comment: Take a look [How to get sample data from dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52413247/1371481)